# Converting image blob url to base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview, base64, blob

I have this code from a library and I wanted to convert the image part to base64.

But I keep on having error on converting blob to base64.

It is a local html file hosted on the device.

```
      <div class="widget file-picker"><input class="ignore fake-file-input"
      placeholder="Click here to upload file. (< 5MB)" readonly=""><button class="btn-icon-only btn-reset"
      aria-label="reset" type="button"><i class="icon icon-refresh"> </i></button><a
      class="btn-icon-only btn-download" aria-label="download"
      download="image-1562651713366.jpg389038873-13_55_28.jpg"
      href="blob:file:///3efb6b21-718c-48d2-8fa1-f59520228804"><i class="icon icon-download"> </i></a>
    <div class="file-feedback "></div>
    <div class="file-preview"><img src="blob:file:///3efb6b21-718c-48d2-8fa1-f59520228804"></div>
  </div>
```

Here is may sample code on converting img to base64. It seems its not working on blob urls.

```
var someimage = $(".file-preview").find("img");
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = someimage.width;
canvas.height = someimage.height;
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(someimage, 0, 0);
dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: And the error message is a national treasure which you can't reveal?

Comment: `someImage` is a jQuery object, you can't draw a jQuery object to the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to incorporate the comment from [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan)

Wait for the image to load and be aware that `someimage` is a jQuery object

```
var someimage = $(".file-preview").find("img");
someimg.on("load", function () { 
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = someimage.width;
    canvas.height = someimage.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(someimage[0], 0, 0);
    dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Comment: Note that jQuery object have no `onload` property, you need to use `.on('load', fn)` instead. Similarly, `someimage` is a jQuery object so supplying that to `drawImage()` will cause an error. You would need `.drawImage(someimage[0], 0, 0);`